# Is it possible to reduce a lambda expression to it's smallest equivalent form?

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics, lambda-calculus

In the Untyped Lambda Calculus, is it possible to reduce any arbitrary expression to it's smallest equivalent form? (defined as an expression with the smallest number of lambda terms) If so, is there an algorithm already defined for this, and what is it's computational complexity? Via the Curry–Howard correspondence, a similar result in logic (first-order logic?) would also be helpful, but not ideal.

Comment: Untyped lambda terms don't correspond to proofs and their types don't correspond to formulas because those terms might be ill-typed. Pure type systems, on the other hand, are strongly normalizing, and types-as-formulas, terms-as-proofs apply to them. I think normalization is big-oh exponential time. Lamping's algorithm is the best we can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "smallest" is a complet order, then it is not possible. Otherwise you could decide equivalence of two terms by checking that their "smallest form" is the same. It is the same reason why you cannot convert a Turing Machine to the smallest equivalent Turing Machine.

In fact even if there are several "smallest" equivalent formula, it is still not possible, because of Rice theorem. (I switch to TM because it is easier to think of for me, but $\lambda$-calculus should be the same)
This is because you could then decide the size of the samllest TM for a language, which is impossible by Rice's theorem.

Comment: An obstacle to this proof idea is the need to distinguish whether two forms of the same length are equivalent.

Comment: Right, in this answer I assumed "smallest" totally orders expressions: expression of the same size are ordered lexicographically. I edit to clarify this.